# How to executable project in C# with right directories

Tags: c#, exception, directory

I am new in C#. I had create a project and i make it executable. I install it to another PC and it runs. I had a picturebox button and when you click on it, it will change the picture. In my PC works perfect because the directory with .gif exists,  but in the other PC it can't find it and throws me exception "Exception HRESULT : {0x800700C1}" .

I load the new picture in picturebox button like below :

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Photos\preview2.gif");
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

I make my application an executable file with Inno Setup Compiler and now i have only an application.exe which include the executable file of my project with the contents files.

When i run my application in another PC tell me that it don't find the .gif

Comment: No... the gif it's inside the project directory. When i make it executable i insert the whole project directory but when i run it in other machine it throws me the directoryonmycomputer/photo.gif

Comment: "install it to another" as in "copied EXE and ignore the rest"? OR could you please clarify what "install" means in your post?

Comment: I make my application an executable file with Inno Setup Compiler and now i have only an application.exe which include the executable file of my project with the contents files.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your images as resources into the project. Right-click your project and look for the "Resources" tab, then add the images to your project.

[image]

Another option is to just copy them to the other machine, into a location you can predict such as "My Pictures", and then load them using:

```
string path =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures),
                 "preview2.gif");
```

Comment: But it's not only pictures it's an a video too so resources can't help me. I use an example this is the reason that i wrote about a picture . And i don't want to copy the folder in other machine. I want to install the executable and make the appls works.

Comment: The sure is that i don't want to copy it each time that i had to install my application to another machine. I don't know how i could put it the video in my project and "take it" with the executable file. Which is the write directory and how it load on executable.

Comment: First of all thank you. How you create an executable project? I know inside the bin folder there is the projectname.exe but if i like to move it to another machine i must to copy the whole project folder?